# On-Page "anchor" scroll links don't scroll to the right place only on the mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use anchor tags to scroll my website.

**Only when I use a mobile** to view the page (or open the browser using a smaller width), it scrolls for about 100px more that it should.

I changed this in the .js file:

```
  $.localScroll({
        offset:{left: 0, top:-100 }
    });
```

*(now works fine with mobiles but not with the desktop browsers)*

from:

```
  $.localScroll({
        offset:{left: 0, top:-184 }
    });
```

*(that dosen't work fine with mobiles.)*

What's causing this problem? 
What can be the best solution?

Comment: Probably `top` value need to be percentage Ex : -10%

Comment: ^ Doesn't work with percentages

Comment: does the answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution **without knowing you code** or knowlage of what is different in mobile code:

```
var problemIfSmallerThanThis = 1200; // Your "problem"-width where the error appears
var docWidth = $(document).width();
if(docWidth > problemIfSmallerThanThis ){
$.localScroll({
        offset:{left: 0, top:-184 }
    });
}else{
$.localScroll({
        offset:{left: 0, top:-100 }
    });
}
```

IT´s just a **WORKAROUND**